# Why is repo not reinstalling after removing it from /etc/yum.repos.d?

Tags: fedora, package-management, yum, repository, dnf

I removed a repo by deleting its file from `/etc/yum.repos.d` using `rm -rf`. Then I tried to install the same repo with `dnf install` but it is not showing up in `/etc/yum.repos.d` or when I run `dnf repolist`.

I assume there is a possibility that the package may still be memorized in `dnf`'s cache so I've tried clearing the cache by typing

`dnf clean expire-cache` and even passing the `--refresh` option to `dnf install` but the repo still doesn't show.

How do I install a repository after removing it manually?

Comment: Exactly what did you try to `dnf install`?

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what repo you deleted and tried to reinstall with your `dnf install ...` command but we can only assume that you tried to do something like this:

```
$ sudo dnf install -y http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/releases/28/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/r/rpmfusion-free-release-28-1.noarch.rpm
Fedora 28 - x86_64                                                                                                                               411 kB/s |  60 MB     02:30
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:00 ago on Mon 23 Jul 2018 02:06:48 AM UTC.
rpmfusion-free-release-28-1.noarch.rpm                                                                                                            40 kB/s |  20 kB     00:00
Dependencies resolved.
...
...
  Preparing        :                                                                                                                                                         1/1
  Installing       : rpmfusion-free-release-28-1.noarch                                                                                                                      1/1
  Verifying        : rpmfusion-free-release-28-1.noarch                                                                                                                      1/1

Installed:
  rpmfusion-free-release.noarch 28-1

Complete!
```

Then deleted the .repo file like this:

```
$ sudo rm /etc/yum.repos.d/rpmfusion-free-updates.repo
```

And then tried to do install again:

```
$ sudo dnf install -y http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/releases/28/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/r/rpmfusion-free-release-28-1.noarch.rpm
RPM Fusion for Fedora 28 - Free                                                                                                                  1.3 MB/s | 754 kB     00:00
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:00 ago on Mon 23 Jul 2018 02:11:12 AM UTC.
rpmfusion-free-release-28-1.noarch.rpm                                                                                                            57 kB/s |  20 kB     00:00
Package rpmfusion-free-release-28-1.noarch is already installed, skipping.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
```

#### Solution

To get things back into shape you need to do a `reinstall` of this RPM not a `install`.

```
$ sudo dnf reinstall -y http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/releases/28/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/r/rpmfusion-free-release-28-1.noarch.rpm
Last metadata expiration check: 0:03:11 ago on Mon 23 Jul 2018 02:11:12 AM UTC.
rpmfusion-free-release-28-1.noarch.rpm                                                                                                            44 kB/s |  20 kB     00:00
Dependencies resolved.
...
...
  Preparing        :                                                                                                                                                         1/1
  Reinstalling     : rpmfusion-free-release-28-1.noarch                                                                                                                      1/2
  Erasing          : rpmfusion-free-release-28-1.noarch                                                                                                                      2/2
  Verifying        : rpmfusion-free-release-28-1.noarch                                                                                                                      1/2
  Verifying        : rpmfusion-free-release-28-1.noarch                                                                                                                      2/2

Reinstalled:
  rpmfusion-free-release.noarch 28-1

Complete!
```

And if we confirm, the *deleted* .repo file is back:

```
$ ls -l /etc/yum.repos.d/rpmfusion-free-updates.repo
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1264 Apr 24 11:27 /etc/yum.repos.d/rpmfusion-free-updates.repo
```

#### Without the URL?

If you want, you can do this without even knowing the URL to the original RPM that was used to setup/install this repo.

Check for the name of the RPM:

```
$ rpm -qa|grep rpmfus
rpmfusion-free-release-28-1.noarch
```

Then do the `dnf reinstall ...` with just the RPM's name instead:

```
$ sudo dnf reinstall -y rpmfusion-free-release
Last metadata expiration check: 0:10:00 ago on Mon 23 Jul 2018 02:11:12 AM UTC.
Dependencies resolved.    
...
...
  Preparing        :                                                                                                                                                         1/1
  Reinstalling     : rpmfusion-free-release-28-1.noarch                                                                                                                      1/2
  Erasing          : rpmfusion-free-release-28-1.noarch                                                                                                                      2/2
  Verifying        : rpmfusion-free-release-28-1.noarch                                                                                                                      1/2
  Verifying        : rpmfusion-free-release-28-1.noarch                                                                                                                      2/2

Reinstalled:
  rpmfusion-free-release.noarch 28-1

Complete!
```

And check that the file's back:

```
$ ls -l /etc/yum.repos.d/rpmfusion-free-updates.repo
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1264 Apr 24 11:27 /etc/yum.repos.d/rpmfusion-free-updates.repo
```

#### What if I don't know the RPM's name?

If you're in the odd predicament that you cannot figure out or recall what RPM to use to reinstall you're still not completely out of luck.

You can see what file you deleted from your `history` command and then run this `rpm` command to learn what RPM provided it:

```
$ rpm -qf /etc/yum.repos.d/rpmfusion-free-updates.repo
rpmfusion-free-release-28-1.noarch
```

And then do the reinstall with the RPM's name as described above.

#### What if the RPM wasn't installed via DNF or YUM?

In your particular case it turns out that the RPM you mentioned: [geogebra-classic-6.0.477.0-201807062103.i386.rpm](http://www.geogebra.org/download/rpm.php?arch=amd64&ver=6), isn't an RPM that contains any YUM .repo files.

```
$ rpm -qpl geogebra-classic-6.0.477.0-201807062103.i386.rpm  | grep yum
$
```

In this scenario, neither `dnf` nor `yum` can provide any assistance because neither knows the URL to reinstall/download this RPM. This is because this RPM was likely originally merely downloaded and installed directly.

When an RPM is installed in this manner, `dnf` & `yum` are blinded to the URL and are merely installing whatever RPM you instruct them to do via the file that's on your local HDD.

Your only recourse in this scenario is to re-download the RPM in question and reinstall it manually using either `dnf`, `yum` or `rpm`.

#### References

- [6.5. Adding, Enabling, and Disabling a DNF Repository](https://docs-old.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/23/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sec-Managing_DNF_Repositories.html)
- [DNF - Fedora Wiki](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/DNF?rd=Dnf)
- [RPMFusion Repo](http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/releases/28/Everything/x86_64/os/repoview/rpmfusion-free-release.html)
- [Third party repositories](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Third_party_repositories)

Comment: This would have been a good answer but it didn't work. However I was able to add the repo manually by re-creating the .repo file, importing the gpgkey and then installing the package I needed. In case you may be curious, this is the [repo link](http://www.geogebra.org/download/rpm.php?arch=amd64&ver=6)

Comment: @MyWrathAcademia - was this RPM installed to begin with? Was it present? If it was I'm not sure how this wouldn't have worked. It's how RPM/YUM/DNF work.

Comment: @MyWrathAcademia - OK so I've investigated your issue further. The RPM you downloaded had no YUM .repo files so your original question of deleting these files doesn't hold up. This RPM is merely an application that was installed, but it was not installed using any .repo file via YUM, you merely downloaded this RPM and installed. In this scenario, `dnf` or `yum` cannot help, since your installation was done by bypassing either of these tools in the downloading of the RPM.

Comment: @MyWrathAcademia - see updates, I've further addressed your scenario.